# Senesitivity of parameters in Matlab ode45

Tags: matlab, parameters, ode

I am building a biological model using matlab.
Does anyone know any toolbox or any other way to check sensitivity of parameters?
I found models in different articles where they just increase/decrease each paramter by 10% and 90%. Is there any elegant or more rigorous approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably you are using ode45( ) because you don't have the analytic solution. Without the analytic solution, I think you are stuck with manually varying the parameters.

Comment: I guess it all depends on what your goals are, and the model you are working with, considering your machine constraints. You can do a simple sensitivity analysis with just two parameters and take 3-5 points for each input parameter, or you can have thousands of parameters and do a thorought analysis with, say, probabilistic sensitivity analysis. What do other publications in that area do? Anyway, this question perhaps belongs to other sites than SO. Try [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for example.